# Importing jQuery script won't work on html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a jQuery external file `confirmPassword.js` which contain keyboard event but when I'm trying to import in my html file my external js file won't work. But when I create jQuery script under html file it work. I'm just trying to save some line of codes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "container">

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <hr>

    <form method = "post" action = "../process/registerProcess.php" >

    <fieldset>

        <div class = "form-field">
            <label for = "username">Username:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label for = "userPassword">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="userPassword">
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label for = "userConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="userConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();">
        </div>

        <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"> </div>

        <div class = "form-field">
            <input type = "submit" name = "registerSubmit" value = "Register">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-field">
            <input type = "reset" name = "registerReset" value = "Reset">
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jQuery Compressed/jquery.js"></script> //jQuery Compressed
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "register/confirmPassword.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**confirmPassword.js**

```
function checkPasswordMatch() 
{
var password = $("#userPassword").val(); //Grab the value of userPassword.
var confirmPassword = $("#userConfirmPassword").val();

if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
}
else
{
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}

}

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#userConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

Comment: why do you have both `onChange` handler specified in html and `.keyup` specified in your external file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are saying your `confirmPassword.js` file doesn't work without jQuery, right?

You are using jQuery in your `confirmPassword.js` file, so you have to have jQuery imported.

EDIT: Found the problem after private chat. The paths to JS files were incorrect.

Comment: Yes exactly. I already imported my jQuery. `jQuery Compressed/jquery.js`

Comment: Yes actually my jQuery keyboard event won't work on my html.

Comment: You mentioned that it works when "...I create jQuery script under html file it work." Can you demonstrate or elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: I mean if I created jQuery script under in my html file it works. But when I'm creating external jQuery it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, so under your html means that you import the jQuery by using `<script>`. What do you mean by external jQuery? Sorry for all the questions, trying to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112324/discussion-between-francisunoxx-and-tedcurrent).